# Python modbus lib for reading file record

Tags: python, modbus

Is there a python modbus lib which implements the functions for reading and writting file records (function codes: 20, 21). The popular Python modbus libraries (pymodbus, pymodbusTCP) provision these functions but do not implement them. Thank you.

Comment: It is implemented in pymodbus, Have you given a try and what was the response you got ? Refer https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/library/pymodbus.html#pymodbus.file_message.ReadFileRecordRequest

Comment: @Sanju If I got this right, I create a sync client and then create a request by instantiating a ReadFileRecordRequest (still I am not sure I get the arguments right though). Then I use the client object to .execute() the request, but all I get is an Exception Response(148, 20, IllegalFunction)

Comment: The response says that the function is not supported by the slave and has nothing to do with pymodbus library. Please check the specs of the slave device and see if that function is really supported.

Comment: @Sanju Yeah, you are right. I updated the device firmware and now I can get files. It seems to be working alright. Thank you! However I had to do some digging in the code because I could not readily find any examples on how to form the requests and send them (e.g. that I needed to build a FileRecord instance). If you care to post an answer with a (full) simple example, I'll accept it.

Comment: The feature is hardly tested. I am posting an answer on how to do it, JFYR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pymodbus does support `ReadFileRecordRequest (0x14)`, its a bit tricky to use , the request expects a list of records to be queried as part of its payload. Each record is a sub request with the following attributes .

> The reference type: 1 byte (must be specified as 6)
>
> The File number: 2 bytes
>
> The starting record number within the file: 2 bytes
>
> The length of the record to be read: 2 bytes.

To facilitate the creation of these sub-requests, pymodbus offers a class `FileRecord` which could be used to represent each sub-request. Note, that there is also a restriction on amount of data to be read (253 bytes), so you will need to ensure the total length of your records is less that that .

Here is a sample code .

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

from pymodbus.file_message import FileRecord, ReadFileRecordRequest

from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient


client = ModbusSerialClient(method="rtu", port="/dev/ptyp0", baudrate=9600, timeout=2)

records = []
# Create records to be read and append to records
record1 = FileRecord(reference_type=0x06, file_number=0x01, record_number=0x01, record_length=0x01)
records.append(record1)

request = ReadFileRecordRequest(records=records, unit=1)
response = client.execute(request)
if not response.isError():
    # List of Records could be accessed with response.records
    print(response.records)
else:
    # Handle Error
    print(response)
```

Note. This feature is hardly tested, If you come across any issues with using this features, please feel free to raise a github issue.